# Add image path to .txt file

Tags: python

I have created the Python script below which prompt I receive the following error when I run it.

```
Average=mean(diff)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\statistics.py", line 315, in mean
    raise StatisticsError('mean requires at least one data point')
statistics.StatisticsError: mean requires at least one data point
```

However, lines 9, 10 and 17 work fine when I comment out the rest of the script. And, the rest of the script works fine when I comment out lines 9, 10 and 17. What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv
from statistics import mean
PyBank_file=r"PyBank\Resources\budget_data.csv"

with open(PyBank_file, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    
    for row in csvreader:
        # months=[row[0] for row in csvreader]
        # Total_Months=len(months)
        amounts=[int(row[1]) for row in csvreader]
        Total_Profits_Losses=sum(amounts)
        diff=[amounts[i+1]-amounts[i] for i in range(len(amounts)-1)]
        Average=mean(diff)
        Greatest_Increase=max(diff)
        Greatest_Decrease=min(diff)
        # print(Total_Months)
        print(Total_Profits_Losses)
        print(Average)
        print(Greatest_Increase)
        print(Greatest_Decrease)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the outer `for row in csvreader:`. You can only iterate over `csvreader` once, the list comprehension for `amounts` uses it all up, and you have no reason to loop over the rows like that. In fact if you uncomment the comprehension for `months` you will have to convert the reader to a list beforehand and use that list instead.

```py
with open(PyBank_file, 'r') as csvfile:
  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  rows = list(csvreader)

months=[row[0] for row in rows]
amounts = [int(row[1]) for row in rows]
```

Comment: I followed your advise and was able to fix it. Thank you, Alex!